# Visual Studio 2017 Linux Makefile Project won't build because of chained prefix

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, makefile, remote-debugging

I have a Linux project witch I developed in vim and now I'd like to go on developing it in Visual Studio with IntelliSense etc.

It's a Makefile project so I need to build it on the Linux machine.

I already created the project and created the connection and it works but I can't build because I am building with a prefix script so I open a new interactive shell with something like this

```
set -i

. "/tools/dist/xxxx-2010.0"/etc/profile
```

I don't think that visual studio can handle such thing.

Is there a way to do it?

I am calling my startprefix script with an alias then it starts the interactive shell and then I enter my make commands for usual but in visual studio it won't build it stops at t he very beginning after executing the first command (which is the startprefix alias)

And another thing is that I don't see any project files in my solution I unloaded and loaded the project but it won't get me the source files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The large keys left and right at your keyboards are the shift-keys. You can try to use it.

Comment: i dont understand what this comment has to do with my problem?

Comment: Asking a question on SO requires a minimum of netiquette. You may want to read #2 in the first bullet list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: better now?! now can anybody help me?

Comment: It's hard to say, what you are looking for. To open an interactive shell you open the Windows Command Prompt or the bash if you have installed the Linux tools for Windows. The `set -i` won't make sense outside a bash like shell. `build it stops`? What does it mean? Do you have several .BAT files and wonder that you missed the `call` to put in front of a called .BAT file? `I don't see any project files` please put separate questions to StockOverflow.

Comment: i want to open the interactive shell withing Visual Studio not outside. outside would not be problem but i want to develop my project in Visual Studio and start the build process on the Linux machine via ssh connection withing Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio C++ for Linux add-in supports MSBuild, makefile and CMake projects. If you already have the makefile then create a new Linux makefile project in VS, add in the source files and hit F5 to build.

Trying to read between the lines of your question:

- C++ for Linux is optional and must be installed
  thru the VS installer.
- Everything, i.e editing, building, debugging, is run in VS from the
  Windows host.
- The source resides on the Windows host (although you can do things with shared drives if needed).
- The Linux remote is just that, remote.
- You might need to interact with the Linux remote to debug an
  X-Windows based GUI application but console applications can be
  debugged entirely on the Windows host.

If you have other commands that you need to run before and/or after the makefile then you can set these up in the VS project settings. Likewise and parameters you need to pass to `make`.

Comment: i solved the problem setting up the code in a virtual box with windows installed and visual studio installed.. now coding and testing there and checking it into my version controll after successfull tests.

Comment: You could also use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) if you want to have everything within your Windows sytem.

Comment: basicly i just want to code withing windows because the linux maschine is a ssh machine without gui and it would take a lot of time to code via x11. so that was the only reason i needed a solution because the applikation runs on a linux server